# How do I use my Jackson KeyDeserializer in nested maps?

Tags: java, json, jackson

### Problem

In an existing application, I have to deserialize possibly deeply nested maps, and apply a custom Jackson de-serializer on all keys at all levels.

Since the application handles all kinds of datamodels dynamically, I cannot use an explicit datamodel with clearly typed maps... Instead, I use a `Map<String, Object>` and checks whether the deserialized `Object` value itself is a `Map`.

This causes the custom de-serializer to **only apply to the top-level map**.

***Update:** It's important to note that I cannot bind a deserializer to *all maps* because my datamodel often have more specific maps as well. I typically have fields that are a generic `Map<String, Object>` for open-ended JSON settings; living together with e.g. `Map<EnumType, Double>` for more explicit bits of configuration.*

---

### Example

To illustrate, I have come up with toy-example below:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new SimpleModule()
    .addKeyDeserializer(String.class, new KeyDeserializer() {
        @Override
        public Object deserializeKey(String s, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) {
            return s.toUpperCase();
        }
    }));
Map<String, Object> value = objectMapper.readValue(
    "{\"zero\": 1, \"two\": { \"three\": 4 }}",
    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}
);
assertThat(value).containsKeys("ZERO", "TWO"); // pass
assertThat((Map) value.get("TWO")).containsKey("THREE"); // fail
```

The last line of code fails:

> java.lang.AssertionError:
> Expecting:
> <{"three"=4}>
> to contain key:
> <"THREE">

I cannot declare the type as `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` because of the int value that is at the same level. If I try, I get:

> Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token

---

### Questions

In this example, what is the best way for me to get upper-cased keys in all nested Maps, even though I need to declare them as `Object`?

Is there an alternative way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working solution.  Though it does not use the KeyDeserializer, as you found out, the KeyDeserializer won't go deep into the JSON to uppercase all the inner JSON field names.

The solution below uses a JsonDeserializer instead of the KeyDeserializer.  I took your example and passed a more complicated JSON to test it.  It traverses through all the objects in the JSON and uppercases all the field names it comes across.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(
            new SimpleModule()
                    .addDeserializer(Map.class, new JsonDeserializer<>() {
                        @Override
                        public Map<String, Object> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                            var map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            while(!p.isClosed()){
                                JsonToken jsonToken = p.nextToken();
                                if (JsonToken.FIELD_NAME.equals(jsonToken)) {
                                    String fieldName = p.getCurrentName().toUpperCase();
                                    jsonToken = p.nextToken();
                                    if (JsonToken.START_OBJECT.equals(jsonToken)) {
                                        map.put(fieldName, getObject(p));
                                    } else if (JsonToken.START_ARRAY.equals(jsonToken)) {
                                        map.put(fieldName, getArray(p));
                                    } else {
                                        map.put(fieldName, getScalar(jsonToken, p));
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            return map;
                        }
                    })
    );
    Map<String, Object> value = objectMapper.readValue(
            "{\"zero\": 1, \"two\": { \"three\": 4 }, \"four\": [\"item\", 5], \"five\": \"string\", \"six\": true, \"seven\": 1.2}",
            new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}
    );
    assertThat(value).containsKeys("ZERO", "TWO"); // pass
    assertThat((Map) value.get("TWO")).containsKey("THREE"); // pass

    System.out.println("JSON = " + new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(value));
}

static Map<String, Object> getObject(JsonParser p) throws IOException {
    var map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    JsonToken jt = p.nextToken();
    while (!JsonToken.END_OBJECT.equals(jt)) {
        if (JsonToken.FIELD_NAME.equals(jt)) {
            String fieldName = p.getCurrentName().toUpperCase();
            jt = p.nextToken();
            if (JsonToken.START_OBJECT.equals(jt)) {
                map.put(fieldName, getObject(p));
            } else if (JsonToken.START_ARRAY.equals(jt)) {
                map.put(fieldName, getArray(p));
            } else {
                map.put(fieldName, getScalar(jt, p));
            }
        }
        jt = p.nextToken();
    }
    return map;
}

static List<Object> getArray(JsonParser p) throws IOException {
    var list = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonToken jt = p.nextToken();
    while (!JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(jt)) {
        if (JsonToken.START_OBJECT.equals(jt)) {
            list.add(getObject(p));
        } else if (JsonToken.START_ARRAY.equals(jt)) {
            list.add(getArray(p));
        } else {
            list.add(getScalar(jt, p));
        }
        jt = p.nextToken();
    }
    return list;
}

static Object getScalar(JsonToken jsonToken, JsonParser p) throws IOException {
    if (JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT.equals(jsonToken) || JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT.equals(jsonToken)) {
        return p.getNumberValue();
    } else if (JsonToken.VALUE_FALSE.equals(jsonToken)) {
        return false;
    } else if (JsonToken.VALUE_TRUE.equals(jsonToken)) {
        return true;
    } else if (JsonToken.VALUE_STRING.equals(jsonToken)) {
        return p.getValueAsString();
    } else if (JsonToken.VALUE_NULL.equals(jsonToken)) {
        return null;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("did not find a scalar for JsonToken = " + jsonToken);
}
```

Right below is the output it generates.

```
JSON = {
  "ZERO": 1,
  "FIVE": "string",
  "SIX": true,
  "FOUR": [
    "item",
    5
  ],
  "TWO": {
    "THREE": 4
  },
  "SEVEN": 1.2
}
```

The code assumes the outermost JSON object is a map.  So it would need a minor update in the JsonDeserializer to handle an array or scalar as the outer outermost JSON.

Comment: Thinking about it further, this does work as expected but I really need to use a Key serializer. The reason is that some maps in my JSON don't have string keys, and I want them to remain unchanged. Binding a deserializer to all `Map`s and assuming that they always deserialize into `Map<String, Object>` breaks if I have some maps where the key is e.g. an enumerated type...

Comment: I've added an update to my problem statement. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I understand the new requirement.  In JSON all keys r strings.  How would you know which keys to uppercase and which to not?

Comment: BTW, you can possibly create multiple ObjectMappers and update the logic of the deserializer that I wrote.  You can generalize the deserializer by putting it into its own class and allowing fields/flags to be set to determine when to upper case the root fields, for example because maybe the root fields are enums and must not be uppercased.

Comment: Some of the JSON maps would be modelled as `Map<EnumType, Double>` in my POJOs and I'd expect Jackson to do the right thing by default. Making all keys uppercase would probably be fine because my EnumType values all have uppercase names, but using this deserializer would give a `Map<String, Object>` which then leads to class-cast exceptions down the line...

Comment: The ObjectMapper needs to be told what type it is mapping to.  So it only does the right thing because it is told what class to make.  `mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<MyEnum, Double>>() {});`

Comment: What I would need, is to use a TypeReference to only use a custom deserializer for `Map<String, Object>`, not for `Map<MyEnum, Double>`. But `SimpleModule:: addDeserializer` expects a class, and type erasure means I can only record the same deserializer for all maps.

Comment: Doesnt exist.  At some point your code needs to know if the JSON it is deserialzing is a Map<String, Object> or is a Map<MyEnum, Double>.  Let me ask, where is the JSON input coming from?  Is there a way to distinguish between the two?

Comment: The JSON is some configuration users edit via a REST API and Web UI. Ideally I would have been able to deserialize instances of `class MyClass { Map<String, Object> freeFormJson; Map<MyEnum, Double> factors } ` but I guess Java’s generic types erasure makes it impossible... :/